# navigation menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, spring

In http://www.visualcase.com/ website got a navigation menu, when I scroll down my mouse button the navigation menu also come down. I want to make that type of navigation menu only using jQuery. Would u guys give me some reference or tutorials so that I can make like that one.

By the way has there any way to build an external navigation menu like template so that I can add that menu anywhere I want (using jQuery).

Moreover, can I use the nav. menu using spring framework?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

After build your menu You just need fix its position, may this help you

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/